# Cannot display a comment on a blog page - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-comments

I have been trying to create a comment section for a blog site. Comments should only be made by the site's users. I am able to make comments and display them in the comment section from the admin panel, but when the users submit comments they don't display in the webpage.

Here are my models.py:

```
class Sight(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_MAX_LEN = 25
    NAME_MAX_LEN = 30
    LOCATION_MAX_LEN = 100
    IMAGE_UPLOAD_TO_DIR = 'destinations/'

    name_of_sight = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Name of Sight',
        max_length=NAME_MAX_LEN,
        unique=True,
    )

    location = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Location',
        max_length=LOCATION_MAX_LEN,
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        # choices=CATEGORIES
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Description',
    )

    post_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )

    pros = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Pros',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    cons = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Cons',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=IMAGE_UPLOAD_TO_DIR,
        verbose_name='Image',
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.name_of_sight, self.user)


class SightComment(models.Model):
    MAX_BODY_LENGTH = 500

    sight = models.ForeignKey(
        Sight,
        related_name='sight_comments',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=False,
    )

    body = models.TextField()

    publication_date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=True,
        null=False,
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.sight.name_of_sight, self.user)
```

My form.py:

```
class SightCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SightComment
        fields = ('body',)
        widgets = {'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'cols': 30, 'rows': 4})}
        labels = {
            "body": ""
        }
```

My view.py - it's interesting how if I leave "new_comment.user = user" whenever the current tries to make a comment on a sight, the author of the sight itself changes to the current user:

```
@login_required(login_url='accounts/login')
def sight_details(request, pk):
    sight = Sight.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comments = sight.sight_comments.all()
    user_like_sights = Sight.objects.filter(pk=pk, user_id=request.user.pk)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SightCommentForm(request.POST, instance=sight)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = user
            new_comment.sight = sight
            new_comment.body = new_comment

            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('sight details', pk)
        else:
            print("Invalid Form")
            print("errors : {}".format(form.errors))
    else:
        form = SightCommentForm()

    context = {
            'is_owner': sight.user_id == request.user.id,
            'sight_author': sight.user,
            'sight': sight,
            'has_user_liked_sight': user_like_sights,
            'likes_count': sight.sightlike_set.count(),
            'form': form,
            'comments': comments,
        }

    return render(request, 'sights/sight_details.html', context)
```

And my template - only the comment part:

```
 {% for comment in comments %}
                            <img src="{{ comment.user.profile.profile_image.url }}" alt="Image"
                                 class="img-fluid mr-3 mt-1" style="width: 45px;">
                            <a href="{% url 'profile details' comment.user.pk %}">{{ comment.user.profile.first_name }}</a>
                            <small><i>on {{ comment.publication_date_and_time }}</i></small>

                            {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
                        {% empty %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <h4>Make a new comment</h4>
                        <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'sight details' sight.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group mb-0">
                                <input type="submit" value="Leave a comment"
                                       class="btn btn-primary font-weight-semi-bold py-2 px-3">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Is `'sight details'` your url name? I am not used to see a space in the middle of a url name - I wonder if that has something to do with the issue. I am referring to the form action`"{% url 'sight details' sight.pk %}"` inside the template

Comment: In case the url name is not an issue, I also notice the line `new_comment.body = new_comment`. I think the body field should already be filled by the user when sending the POST request, so maybe that line isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Martin. The url 'sight details' works as I can open the details page without any problems. With or without 'new_comment.body = new_comment' part the comments do not show on the details page.

Comment: Maybe adding a few print statements would help debugging it?: add a `print("this form is valid")` inside the `if form.is_valid:` / add a `print("the correct view is being called")` at the beginning of your view / maybe another one inside the if that checks of POST method. Then you submit a new comment and check in your terminal if you can see the print statements or not. From there new ideas can arise. I am just brainstorming :) , hope it helps

Comment: I tried your suggestions, Martin, but it gives no errors in the terminal when printing the statements. I'll keep digging what might be the problem.